# R: how to count the number of < 6 digits numbers in a column

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 80 thousand rows like the following:

```
 A        B
 1520     1
 301923   2
 200900   3
 a
 adjj
 2256
 total
```

I want to count the number of <6-digit numbers (e.g. 1520, 2256) that appeared in column A. Since column A also has strings, I am at a lost of how I can count the numbers properly.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed for lack of focus. I found the question to be clear, succinct and useful, with a correspondingly helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can subset the numbers only elements with `grep`, count the number of characters with `nchar`, check whether they are less than 6 and get the `sum` of the logical `vector`.

```
sum(nchar(grep("^[0-9]+$", df1$A, value=TRUE)) <6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. You can convert to numeric. Any non-numeric values will be changed to NA>

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("1520","301923","200900","a","adjj","2256","total"))
suppressWarnings(x<-as.numeric(as.character(A))); 
df$A[!is.na(x) & x<1e5]
# [1] 1520 2256
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c('1520','301923','200900','a','adjj','2256','total'));
length(grep('^[0-9]{1,5}$',df$A));
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Nice, I was about to post `sum(grepl("^[0-9]{1,5}$", x$A))`